# SQL Contains method

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I'm trying to verify via SQL if a string f.ex. AB123CD contains the number 1 and 3, or f.ex. number 2 and 3.

My attempt was the following:
-> SELECT * FROM Book WHERE Category LIKE '%${13}%';

I'm still learning, for this reason I am grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` strings aren't regular expressions. They're limited as to the wildcard characters they use. To use `LIKE` for this purpose you need:

```
 SELECT * FROM Book WHERE (Category LIKE '%1%' AND Category LIKE '%3%');
```

Or you can use SQLite's GLOB or REGEXP filters.